# Jersey Jackson JSON deserialization of response entity results in blank fields

Tags: java, rest, jersey, deserialization

Ive come up against a problem. When my POJO is being deserialized by the Jersey client via the call

```
jersey.api.ClientResponse#getEntity(OrderCostSummary.class)
```

all the fields i.e subTotal, shippingCost, tax and total are null in the response json.

I initially thought it would have been a problem to do with the Money class, i.e the ObjectMapper not knowing how to deserialize this class but I have other api calls which return response entities with Money fields that deserialize without any issues.

This is the JSON being returned back from the server:

```
{ "orderCostSummary":{
  "subTotal":{
     "amount":"9.99",
     "currency":"GBP"
  },
  "shippingCost":{
   "money": {
     "amount":2.95,
     "currency":"GBP"
     }
  },
  "tax":{
     "amount":0,
     "currency":"GBP"
  },
  "total":{
     "amount":12.94,
     "currency":"GBP"
  }}}
```

The POJO

```
public class OrderCostSummary {
private Money subTotal;
private Money shippingCost;
private Money tax;
private Money total;

/**
 * Instantiates a new Order cost summary.
 */
public OrderCostSummary() {
}

public Money getSubTotal() {
    return subTotal;
}

public void setSubTotal(Money subTotal) {
    this.subTotal = subTotal;
}

public Money getShippingCost() {
    return shippingCost;
}

public void setShippingCost(Money shippingCost) {
    this.shippingCost = shippingCost;
}

public Money getTax() {
    return tax;
}

public void setTax(Money tax) {
    this.tax = tax;
}

public Money getTotal() {
    return total;
}

public void setTotal(Money total) {
    this.total = total;
}

public class Money {
private BigDecimal amount;
private Currency currency;
```

My money POJO

```
public Money() { }

public Money(BigDecimal amount, Currency currency) {
    this.amount = amount;
    this.currency = currency;
}

public BigDecimal getAmount() {
    return amount;
}

public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}

public Currency getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(Currency currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
}
```

Comment: That sounds a lot like the faulty deserialization is an attempt to convert an object that is not an OrderCostSummary. Nevertheless, I wonder if adding @JsonProperty annotations would help.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps if you try this :

```
public class OrderCostSummary implements Serializable {
    @JsonDeserialize(as=Money.class)
    private Money subTotal;
    //And do the same with other fields.
    ...
}
```

Notice that i added 'implements Serializable' which is better for POJO that are serialized/deserialized

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your structure is not always the same :

This structure :

```
{
   "orderCostSummary":{
      "subTotal":{
         "amount":"9.99",
         "currency":"GBP"
      },
      "shippingCost":{
         "amount":2.95,
         "currency":"GBP"
      },
      "tax":{
         "amount":0,
         "currency":"GBP"
      },
      "total":{
         "amount":12.94,
         "currency":"GBP"
      }
   }
}
```

is different from this structure :

```
{
   "orderCostSummary":{
      "subTotal":{
         "money":{
            "amount":"9.99",
            "currency":"GBP"
         }
      },
      "shippingCost":{
         "money":{
            "amount":2.95,
            "currency":"GBP"
         }
      },
      "tax":{
         "money":{
            "amount":0,
            "currency":"GBP"
         }
      },
      "total":{
         "money":{
            "amount":12.94,
            "currency":"GBP"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry @Basemasta I realised that I added the money element to the json in a bid to try and resolve the matter and left it in accidentally when posting it here.

I have managed to get it to work. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that the following json should have been deserialized with the call

```
jersey.api.ClientResponse#getEntity(ClassThatHoldsOrderCostSummary.class)
```

Once the object has been deserialized I can then call

```
classThatHoldsOrderCostSummary.getOrderCostSummary()
```